# No Bootable device found on starting my laptop

Tags: 22.04, windows-11

My laptop came with pre installed **windows 11**, but later on i installed **ubuntu**, now i wanted to install windows but it was `not detecting the ssd` while installing, so i searched on internet i found out that **file system is not supported** for windows as it was *linux file system* , so i **changed the main partition of my ssd to basic one (windows)** and restarted laptop to install windows but didn't work but now the pc is showing no bootable device found..... How to fix it ??